# Mysqli prepared statement num_rows with multiple parameters

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following script:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');

$statement = $mysqli->stmt_init();

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? AND active = 1';
$statement->prepare($query);
$parameters = array('i');
$inputParameters = array(10);
foreach ($inputParameters as $param) {
    $parameters[] =& $param;
}
call_user_func_array(array($statement, 'bind_param'), $parameters);
$statement->execute();
$statement->store_result();
echo $statement->num_rows;
?>
```

Which returns exactly the right number of rows.

But when I change the script to:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');

$statement = $mysqli->stmt_init();

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? AND active = ?';
$statement->prepare($query);
$parameters = array('ii');
$inputParameters = array(10, 1);
foreach ($inputParameters as $param) {
    $parameters[] =& $param;
}
call_user_func_array(array($statement, 'bind_param'), $parameters);
$statement->execute();
$statement->store_result();
echo $statement->num_rows;
?>
```

It returns 0. Does anyone have an explanation for that? To me it looks like num_rows stops working as soon as you have more than 1 param bound to the statement.

p.s: in the full script there's a reason to use `call_user_func_array` here, not using `call_user_func_array` gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after a lot of debugging: `$parameters` will be `array('ii', 1, 1)` in the second code. This is because of the reference used there. Changing `foreach ($inputParameters as $param) {` to `foreach ($inputParameters as &$param) {` fixed the problem